# Eclipse/PyDev: Sync System PYTHONPATH runs continuously

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, pythonpath

When Eclipse/PyDev is open I see an operation running in the background, over and over (as if stuck in an infinite loop), in the lower right status area telling me "Sync System PYTHONPATH (100%)".  I have a single Python interpreter configured, everything runs fine, but I wonder if this continual update of the PYTHONPATH is something to be concerned about.  Maybe there's something amiss which is triggering this sync operation to occur every second or so?

Eclipse:
Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1)
Build id: 20140925-1800
PyDev:
Version: 3.9.0.201411111611

OS: Windows 7 64-bit

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: I'm also seeing this problem in Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers, version 2022-12 (4.26.0), Build id: 20221201-1913, running on Linux Ubuntu 22.04. It's been stuck on "Sync System PYTHONPATH" with the line "Module resolved: opt.foxitsoftware.foxitreader.fxplugins.libcloudloginplugin", using 100% of one CPU, for days.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I managed to get rid of it by disabling setting which says *"Check consistency when related files (i.e.: .py, .pth) in the PYTHONPATH change?"* in the Eclipse preferences.

As shown in the screenshot below, go to Window -> Preferences -> PyDev -> Interpreters -> uncheck the box next to "Check consistency when related files (i.e.: .py, .pth) in the PYTHONPATH change?" -> click "Apply and Close".

Restart Eclipse.

After restarting Eclipse, the infinite loop did not appear any more.

[image: Screenshot of Eclipse configuration]

**Notes:**

1. This looks like a bug to me. I had the issue using LiClipse 1.4.0 but also had it with 1.0.0 so it does not seem to be very recent.
2. If you still have the problem, you may also have to uncheck the box for "Check initial consistency (in 1 minute) after startup?"

Comment: This appears to have fixed things for me as well.  Thanks, Germain!

Comment: As a note, did you have your CPU usage high in this case? i.e.: it shouldn't be a problem if you only have the process showing in the progress bar -- If you do the proposed solution, when you add a new package through pip you'll have to remember to manually add the paths to your installation -- or restart as you left the 'check initial consistency' turned on :)

Comment: Indeed I had high CPU usage before I did the change, on top of the annoying blinking in the progress bar.

Comment: I also had to uncheck the box for  "Check initial consistency (in 1 minute) after startup?". This is in Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers, version 2022-12 (4.26.0), Build id: 20221201-1913, running on Linux Ubuntu 22.04. It's been stuck on "Sync System PYTHONPATH" with the line "Module resolved: opt.foxitsoftware.foxitreader.fxplugins.libcloudloginplugin", using 100% of one CPU, for days. No number of computer restarts nor Eclipse restarts would fix it prior to unchecking both those boxes.

Comment: Update: turns out PyDev is no longer maintained, I think, and doesn't work with my (the latest) version of Eclipse. So, I've uninstalled PyDev and installed LiClipse instead as a possible alternative.